# Better way to join table valued function

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to generate a table that holds a client age analysis at a certain time. My source data is from Pastel Evolution accounting system.

They have a table valued function `[_efnAgedPostARBalancesSum]` that takes 2 Parameters (date and client link) and returns `Age1`, `Age2`, etc for entered client link.  I need to get the ageing for all the clients in the client table.

I managed to get it working by using cross apply as per below, but it takes a long time to execute. If I run the age analysis from within Pastel it takes about 20 seconds, in Sql it takes about 6 minutes.

The function is encrypted so I cannot see what it does. I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.
Is there a more efficient alternative to cross apply?

```
SELECT 
  f.AccountLink, 
  f.AccountBalance, 
  f.Age1, 
  f.Age2, 
  f.Age3, 
  f.Age4, 
  f.Age5, 
  f.Age6, 
  f.Age7 
FROM
  Client 
  CROSS APPLY [_efnAgedPostARBalancesSum] ('2014-09-30', Client.DCLink) AS f
```

Comment: Any chance of using a `JOIN` instead of `CROSS APPLY`?

Comment: @MartinParkin - I doubt it since the OP doesn't know what is within `_efnAgedPostARBalancesSum`

Comment: I tried that, but then I cannot use Client.DCLink as a variable in the function. Unless I am missing something?

Comment: are the values within `Client.DCLink` unique? or can there be many duplicate DCLink

Comment: They are unique - it is a integer Primary Key to the Client table.

Comment: in that case unless we know what's inside `[_efnAgedPostARBalancesSum]` I think its hard to optimize this any further

Comment: What I was hoping is that there is an alternative to CROSS APPLY to passing the DCLink values to the function. I have limited knowledge of SQL.

Comment: User defined functions are really bad for performance (except inline functions, which I would assume this is not) -- and you can't really do anything to it, you should just try to avoid them completely.

Comment: You could use SQL Profiler to see what queries the Paste! system sends to SQL Server during its 20 second run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like an AR aging bucket function from the outside - and probably has custom bucket sizes (given the generic age1, age2, etc).  They're notoriously compute intensive.  Its the kind of query that often spawns the need for a separate BI database as an OLTP system is not ideal for analytical queries.  Its not only slow to run, its also likely to be impacting other work in your OLTP system while this function is banging on it.

You can bet it's looking at the due dates from the various documents that contain balances due (very likely several sources).  They might not all be indexed on the due date columns.  Look for that first.  If you run the query in SSMS with show plan on, it may suggest one or more indexes to speed the execution - right-click in the query window and select "Show Actual Query Plan".  From this, you can at least discover the tables that are being touched and the predicates involved in gathering the data...and you might get lucky with indexing.

There's no telling how efficiently the function computes the buckets.  If they're not using some kind of window functions, it can be kind of horrible.  You might find it advantageous to write your own UDF to get only what you want.  Since it's generic, it may have a lot more work to do to cover all the possible bases - something your organization may not need.

If it is an inline function, you might get some relief by asking only for the columns you really need to look at.  They're returning (at least) 7 buckets and a lot of AR reporting and analysis needs only 3 (the 30, 60, 90 day buckets, for example).  It might also be worth doing a little pre-analysis to find out what clients you need to apply the function to - to keep from having to run it against your whole client domain.

Just looking at the function name - makes me think it's not a documented API per se.  Encryption reinforces this hunch.  Not sure how badly you really want to use such a function - no telling how it might get refactored (or removed) going forward.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I managed to trace where the data comes from and can now get the 6 ageing totals with customer details in less than a second.